# Multifile and dvi output from the 'master.tex'

Tags: external-files, auctex

I have a report composed of multiple files where I name the master file as 'master.tex' and set

(setq-default TeX-master "master")

in my .emacs file.

I compile the master file and try to click the 'view dvi button' on the auctex toolbar in emacs, however it does not open any viewer nor it gives any error messages.

But if I open one of the files that is included from the master file and compile the whole document from under the included file and try to view the resulting dvi, it works and I can see the complete dvi. The question is that why can't I do the same from the master file, I mean viewing?(Trying on a simple example with two files, I can see the dvi from both the master and the included file, so there is sth mistaken for the above case.)

Compiling master file goes fine along with bibtex however viewing does not work, what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you try the following steps : 1. Delete the produced .dvi file; 2. Compile the document from under the included file; 3. Switch to the master file and try to open the viewer from there.

Comment: same, I can not view it... however trying to view that from the 'included' file works fine.

Comment: Try hitting `C-c C-v` from the master file and the included file, and check that the command proposed by `emacs` is the same in both cases.

Comment: Are there any news here? Did you solve the issue in the meanwhile and are able to provide a self answer? If not, are there any details you can add to the question? That would make it appear on the main page again.